# Resize matplotlib object within gridspec cell (matshow and colorbar size mismatched)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

The matshow and colorbar objects do not fill the same space inside the gridspec cells and therefore they are different heights.

Usually I would use the colorbar 'shrink' argument, but this does not seem to work when nested in a gridspec object

How can I shrink the colorbar object without resizing the matshow heat map?

Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randint(0, 3, 10000).reshape(100, 100)))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(10, 10)

#### other axes removed for simplicity

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:,:8])

# plot heatmap
cax = ax2.matshow(df, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.YlGn, aspect='equal')
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:,8])

fig.colorbar(cax, cax=ax3)

plt.tight_layout()
gs.update(wspace=2, hspace=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image: matshow and colorbar are slightly (annoyingly) different heights]

## EDIT: Annotated image for clarification

[image]

Comment: The heatmap and colorbar ' are different heights'. In your attached image they look the same height to me. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: They're really close but not quite the same! 
I have added another image to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use matplotlib [AxesDivider](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axesdivider%22AxisDivider%22). Below is an example using the data from your question:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randint(0, 3, 10000).reshape(100, 100)))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(10, 10)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:,:8])

im = ax2.matshow(df,interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.YlGn, aspect='equal')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph, which to my eye looks like they are the same size:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I needed